# Regular expression to only return every other match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will match humanly readable quoted values. As one example, XML attributes. The problem I'm running into is that the data between quoted areas is actually quoted as well if you consider an attribute's ending quote and a subsequent attribute's beginning quote. Here's the expression I have so far:

```
(?<=\")(?(?!\s+\")[^\"]+)(?=\")
```

What I tried to express in plain English was: A quote (don't capture it), if not followed by just spaces terminating in another quote, match anything not a quote that is followed by another quote (not capturing the last quote).

and here's my sample data:

```
<computer name = "printserver" model = "1000ZS" />
```

The regex produces 3 matches:

1. printserver
2. model =
3. 1000ZS

I think that if I could find a way to tell the regex engine to skip every other occurrence I'd have it.

Here's another sample data set, sort of like QML class attributes:

```
field1: "value1" field2: "value2" field3: "value3"
```

I can "see" the quoted data, but extracting it via regex is beating me :-)

I'm using the .NET 4.5 System.Text.RegularExpressions framework in my project. I'm not targeting a specific markup like XML, JSON, QML, etc. but am looking for a general purpose regex that would just grab the quoted values similar to how we interpret the data as humans...

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use XML parser?

Comment: I would use a regexp that captures any (key)="(value)", then you get the value from the second group.

Comment: I edited my question in an attempt to provide greater clarity. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always consume the quote in your match:

```
\"([^\"]+)\"
```

And extract the part you need from the first capture group.

If it's explicitly a quote preceded by a space, then you can use the part you used, with a little tweak:

```
\"((?:(?!\s+\")[^\"])+)\"
```

Of if you just know that the string contains simple patterns like that, maybe something like this:

```
(?:(?!\s+\")[^\"])+(?=\")
```

Comment: With a slight tweak on your first pattern, \"([^\"]*)\" , I only capture the regions I want to capture, including the quotes. Is it possible to consume, but not capture the quotes? Thanks

Comment: @Jace The regex is not capturing the quotes at all. The first capture group has only the part between the quotes. The last regex doesn't match the quotes at all, and you can add `(?<=\")` at the start if you use `*` instead of `+` as quantifier, because you'd get extra results otherwise.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks a million. I'm learning, albeit slowly :-)

Comment: @Jace Haa xD Don't worry, learning slowly or quickly won't change what you have learned :) You're welcome!